# Problem using the prependTo() in jQuery

Tags: jquery, prepend

I am having a problem trying to use the prependTo() function in jQuery... for some reason I can't get this to work

```
$("
<div id="note178" class="note"> 
 <div class="delete"><a href="/chart-notes/delete/178" onclick="$.ajax({ dataType: 'script', url: '/chart-notes/delete/178'}); return false;"><img src='/images/icons/delete.png'></a></div> 
 <div class="timestamp">1 minute ago </div> 
 <div class="content">ñasdas dasdasdasd conclusión</div>  
</div>
").prependTo(".notes").fadeIn("slow");
```

Although when doing it like this, it works fine

```
$.ajax({
  url:'/chart-notes/show/<cfoutput>#chartnote.id#</cfoutput>',
  success: function(data) {
   $(data).prependTo(".notes").fadeIn("slow");

   // Scroll to the top of the annotations
   $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: $(".notes").offset().top}, 1000);

   // Clear the form
   $('#chartnote-notes').val("");  
  }
 });
```

The "data" response from that success function is the same

```
<div id="note178" class="note"> 
 <div class="delete"><a href="/chart-notes/delete/178" onclick="$.ajax({ dataType: 'script', url: '/chart-notes/delete/178'}); return false;"><img src='/images/icons/delete.png'></a></div> 
 <div class="timestamp">1 minute ago </div> 
 <div class="content">ñasdas dasdasdasd conclusión</div>  
</div>
```

As before

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this one.

```
$("<div id=\"note178\" class=\"note\"> "+
" <div class=\"delete\"><a href=\"/chart-notes/delete/178\" onclick=\"$.ajax({ dataType: 'script', url: '/chart-notes/delete/178'}); return false;\"><img src='/images/icons/delete.png'></a></div> "+
" <div class=\"timestamp\">1 minute ago </div> "+
" <div class=\"content\">ñasdas dasdasdasd conclusión</div>  "+
"</div>").prependTo(".notes").fadeIn("slow");
```

You need to escape the double quotes and you cannot have literal new lines in javascript strings. thus the following syntax which concatenates multiple strings.

```
"..." +
"..." +
"..."
```

Comment: Thank you, that was it... for some reason I didn't know ColdFusion had a function to escape Javascript strings... I feel like a fool :) thanks

Answer (score 3):

Also, IIRC, you have to set *"display: none"* for #note178 before calling *fadeIn*, otherwise you won't see any fade effect.

Comment: +1 - Funny enough - I didn't need the answer to the question asked on this page...I just needed the "display:none" tip!

Answer (score 0):

Try changing all of the double quotes inside of the main `$("...")` to single quotes. For example, `'note178'`

Comment: Tried that... I just can't get around the idea of the other .ajax working and not this "by hand" approach... both produce the same code when debugging... is there a jQuery text parse going on under the hood?

Answer (score 0):

A JavaScript string cannot literal newlines.

```
alert("12
       34");
```

Gives the error: `unterminated string literal`